# HQL Invalid Path in multiple Join

Tags: hibernate, hql

I've tried to translate this Query in HQL :

```
SELECT t2.code_acs, t3.lib, t5.libelle
FROM
    debit t1
    INNER JOIN saci t2 ON t1.mat_dep=t2.dep
    INNER JOIN departement t5 ON t5.numero = t2.dep
    INNER JOIN dbo.rushServices t3 ON t2.code_acs=t3.acs
    LEFT JOIN l_debit_saci t4 ON t4.id_debit=t1.id AND t4.code_acs=t2.code_acs
WHERE t4.code_acs    IS    NULL
ORDER BY t3.lib
```

My HQL Query is :

```
buffer = new StringBuilder();
buffer.append("SELECT SA ");
buffer.append("FROM DebitMod D ");
buffer.append("INNER JOIN SaciMod SA ");
buffer.append("INNER JOIN SA.departement DE ");
buffer.append("WHERE D.id = :debitId ");
buffer.append("AND D.matriculeDepartement = DE.numero");
buffer.append("AND SAS.service is null ");

hqlQuery = session.createQuery(buffer.toString());
hqlQuery.setInteger("debitId", idDebit);
```

And My three models are :

**DebitMod :**

```
....
@Column(name = "mat_dep", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "bpchar")
private String matriculeDepartement = null;
....
```

**SaciMod :**

```
....
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "dep", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "bpchar")
private DepartementMod departement = null;
....
```

**DepartementMod :**

```
....
@Id
@Column(name = "numero", nullable = false)
private String numero = null;

@Column(name = "libelle", nullable = false)
private String libelle = null;
....
```

**RushServiceMod :**

```
....
@Id
@Column(name = "acs", nullable = false)
private String acs = null;

@Column(name = "lib", nullable = true)
private String libelle = null;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "service", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<SaciMod> sacis = null;
....
```

**DebitSaciMod :**

```
....
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_debit", nullable = false)
private DebitMod debit = null;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "code_acs", nullable = false)
private RushServiceMod service = null;
....
```

When i test the HQL Query i got this error:

*org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.InvalidPathException: Invalid path: 'DE.numero'*

What i've forgot ?

Thank's for your help

Comment: how do you join DebitMod  and SaciMod .. try to add more entity code

Comment: i've add this and i've same error : 

buffer.append("INNER JOIN SA.service R ");
buffer.append("LEFT JOIN D.sacis SAS ")

Comment: ok but add to the question so we can see how the dependencies  are mapped between entities. also add the Department entity

Comment: I've added two others entity in question @MaciejKowalski

Comment: again.. crucial here is dependency between DebitMod and SaciMod. Try to add the entity deps

Comment: `INNER JOIN SA.departement DE`: that is a valid HQL join. But `INNER JOIN SaciMod SA`: that is not valid. Joins use associations between entities.

Comment: how to do that then ? i've put all models and dependecies between them

Comment: By adding the necessary association(s) if they don't exist yet. You need associations to be able to do joins.

Comment: I dont have another associations